# Jgraphx styles applied to circleLayout

Tags: java, jgraphx

I'm using JGraphX to draw a graph,using mxCircleLayout as basic representation, but I want to change some behavior. For example I want the  EDGESTYLE_TOPTOBOTTOM, so before build mxGraphComponent I define a new edge style:

'
    JGraphXAdapter graphAdapter = new JGraphXAdapter(this.stradario.getStradario());

```
graphAdapter.getModel().beginUpdate();
try {
    Map<String, Object> edgeStyle = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    edgeStyle = graphAdapter.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();
    edgeStyle.put(mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE, mxConstants.EDGESTYLE_TOPTOBOTTOM);
    mxStylesheet stylesheet = new mxStylesheet();
    stylesheet.setDefaultEdgeStyle(edgeStyle);
    graphAdapter.setStylesheet(stylesheet);

} finally {
    graphAdapter.getModel().endUpdate();
}

mxCircleLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(graphAdapter);

layout.execute(graphAdapter.getDefaultParent());

mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graphAdapter);  
graphComponent.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);
```

'
The graph was drawn as a circle layout, but edges are not in TOPTOBOTTOM  style.
[First draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/936S9.png)
Then, if I draw a new edge, or I change an existing one, the edge is drawn with TOPTOBOTTON style.

[Modified edge take the TOPTOBOTTOMSTYLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UjaG.png)

I don't understand why the initial drawn is without TOPTOBOTTOM style and the modified edge was done with the new style.

Answer (score 0):

The layout disables edge styles by default. Set the disableEdgeStyle member to false.

```
mxCircleLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(graphAdapter);
layout.setDisableEdgeStyle(false);
layout.execute(graphAdapter.getDefaultParent());
```